# Use an engine inside a mountable engine as "plugin"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I´m trying to extend a mountable engine with another engine. Goal is to have `modules` (mountable/namespaced), which can be extended by `plugins` (non-namespaced).

Right now I have the following (simplified) structure:

```
main_app
├── modules
├── ├── module_1
│   ├── ├── plugins
│   │   ├── ├── plugin_1
```

to load a `module`, I do this in the main app´s Gemfile, which works fine:

```
gem 'module_1', path: "modules/module_1"
```

My problem is to load the module´s `plugin`. I tried this in module_1´s Gemfile:

```
gem 'plugin_1', path: "plugins/plugin_1"
```

Which results in a Bundler error `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "plugin_1"`. Absolute path (modules/module_1/plugins/plugin_1) also didn´t work.

How do I load an engine inside an engine? Is this even possible?

Comment: Bundler uses a gem's gemspec instead of the actual Gemfile, so you can't specify a local path.  You can however use: bundle config local.plugin_1 /home/user/workspace/plugin_1/

Consider referencing the git repo in your Gemfile instead of path.